# Returning Invalid Keys After Calling Method in Custom Validation with Simple Schema

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

So up until this point my experience with Collection2/Simple Schema has been basic at best. Now, I'm trying to validate values for 'types' based on documents in a Type collection.

```
@Data = new Mongo.Collection 'data'
Data.attachSchema new SimpleSchema
    'types':
        'type': [String]
        'label': 'Types'
        'custom': ->
            if @isSet
                Meteor.call 'isType', @value, (error, result) ->
                    if !result
                        Data.simpleSchema().namedContext('admin_update').addInvalidKeys [
                            'name': 'types'
                            'type': 'notAllowed'
                        ]
    'otherField':
        'type': Number
        'label': 'Other Field'
        'optional': true
```

So far, my isType Method has been validating the values correctly, but regardless of whether it returns true or false, it stores the value anyway (even though the form flashes the error message briefly). I don't think I grasp custom validation well enough to figure out how to do this correctly, so any and all help would be appreciated, even if it's just pushing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `allowedValues` field, which can take an array or a function. Use a function.

```
MyCollection.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  types: {
    type: [String],
    allowedValues: function () {
      // assuming "Types" is the collection.
      return Types.find().map(function (doc) {
        return doc._id;
      });
    }
  }
}));
```

This validates on the back end so the publications and subscriptions will not be a problem.

Comment: For some reason using a function for allowedValues never occurred to me. I tried a map like you suggested above and threw in a subscription since I'm dealing with autoform. The issue now is, since autoform detects a value for allowedValue, it turns what would be multiple blank text fields into a multiselect field, and it doesn't populate that select with any values, even when they are returned properly. My best guess is that it has to do with the asynchronous call, but a console log show all correct results immediately on the first result, so I just don't even know what's going on anymore.